# Python windows path

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a path in Python (windows) and frustratingly enough it gives me wrong path every time. The path I'm trying to build is `C:\Users\abc\Downloads\directory\[log file name]`.

So when I use `print(os.getcwd())` it returns `C:\Users\abc\Downloads\directory` which is fine. But when I try to use the os join in python, `(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()),GetServiceConfigData.getConfigData('logfilepath')))`
it returns only `C:\Logs\LogMain.log` and not the desired output. `(Path.cwd().joinpath(GetServiceConfigData.getConfigData('logfilepath')))` also returns the same result.

`logfilepath` is an XML string `<add key="logfilepath" value="\Logs\LogMain.log" />`

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` works, but `os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()),GetServiceConfigData.getConfigData('logfilepath'))` doesn't - try deleting `os.path.abspath` in the not-working line. And try `print(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))`.

Comment: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(),GetServiceConfigData.getConfigData('logfilepath'))` ->C:\Logs\LogMain.log
`Path.cwd().joinpath(GetServiceConfigData.getConfigData('logfilepath'))`->
C:\Logs\LogMain.log
`os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())` -> C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\directory

Comment: Wow, that's really weird ... What does it print if you execute `print(os.path.join("C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\directory", "LogMain.log"), os.path.join(os.path.abspath("C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\directory"), "LogMain.log")` ?

Comment: first check what you get with `GetServiceConfigData.getConfigData('logfilepath')` - if it gives `C:\Logs\LogMain.log` or `\Logs\LogMain.log` then it is absolut path and it will not `join` with other folder. You would have to remobe starting \ from `\Logs\LogMain.log` to get relative path `Logs\LogMain.log` and then it will `join` with other folder. OR you should get only filename from `\Logs\LogMain.log` using ie, `split('\')[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, in the end it was solved by removing 1 backslash.

### `<add key="logfilepath" value="\Logs\LogMain.log" />`

to

### `<add key="logfilepath" value="Logs\LogMain.log" />`

Answer (score 0):

Your `logfilepath` is `\Logs\LogMain.log` and this is absolute path (without drive), not relative path, and not only filename - so it will not join as you expect.

When you try to join absolute path then it keeps only drive and replaces previous absolute path.

You have to get only `filename` from `\Logs\LogMain.log` - ie.

```
 logfilepath.split('\\')[-1]
```

to have only `LogMain.log` and finally get

```
 C:\Users\abc\Downloads\directory\LogMain.log
```

---

```
folder = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

logfilepath = GetServiceConfigData.getConfigData('logfilepath')
filename = logfilepath.split('\\')[-1]

os.path.join(folder, filename)
```

---

**EDIT**

If `logfilepath` is object `pathlib.Path` like

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('\Logs\LogMain.log')
```

then you may get only filename using

```
p.name
```

Comment: Your point is absolutely correct. Albeit I wanted to it to be in a separate folder like "Logs\LogMain.log"; nevertheless, problem solved by your suggestion!

Comment: if you want in separated folder then you have to remove starting \  before `Logs`